# Injecting a local css into UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I'm trying to "inject" a local css file into downloaded xhtml file.

I found many examples of how to do it, but it just doesn't work for me...

Here is my code:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *cssPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.css"]; 

    NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var cssNode = document.createElement('link');"
                "cssNode.type = 'text/css';"
                "cssNode.rel = 'stylesheet';"
                "cssNode.href = '%@';", cssPath];
    js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cssNode);", js];
    //m_webview is a member 
    [m_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also had trouble doing this.

I was trying to load an HTML file from a server and change the styling using a local CSS file.

At first I used

```
[webView loadRequest:reqObj];
```

And when it hit `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` i was trying to push the CSS file as a child to 'head':

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *cssPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"style.css"]; 

NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var cssChild = document.createElement('link');"
                "cssChild = 'text/css';"
                "cssChild = 'stylesheet';"
                "cssChild = '%@';", cssPath];
js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cssChild);", js];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
}
```

So... it didn't work...

then i tried

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];    
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

(I copied the HTML string into htmlString) and then, inside `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` I injected the CSS as in the code above. And it worked!

But... my HTML file is stored in a remote server and I didn't have the HTML string, so I used

```
NSString* myFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://blablabla.com/file.html"];
NSString* myFileURLString = [myFile stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSData *myFileData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myFileURLString]];
NSString* myFileHtml = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:myFileData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
```

To get the HTML. Now, I have the raw HTML text inside ' myFileHtml '.
I now use

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];    
[webView loadHTMLString:myFileHtml baseURL:baseURL];
```

And catching the response in ' webViewDidFinishLoad ', injecting my CSS file into it and it worked :)

Maybe there's another, more elegant, solution to this problem, but this is what I came up with...

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks!
That did work.
I just had to add '[myFileData release];'

Answer (score 1):

> cssNode.href = '%@';", cssPath];

The line above fails because it tries to fetch the file from the webserver. Using something like:

> cssNode.href = 'file://%@';", cssPath];

accesses the local file system. You can use Safari's developer mode to inspect the iPhone simulator and see whether file is found and loaded.

---

I eventually ended up implementing inline stylesheets instead of linking to stylesheet. Here's the code that works for me

```
NSError *error;
NSString *css = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"stylesheet" ofType:@"css"] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
css = [css stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "]; // js dom inject doesn't accept line breaks, so remove them

NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var styleNode = document.createElement('style');"
                "styleNode.type = 'text/css';"
                "styleNode.innerHTML = ' %@ ';", css];
js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleNode);", js];

[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this while looking for an answer to the same question.  I'm loading an HTML page from a web server into a UIWebView.  The HTML already has lots of CSS, appropriate for web viewing.  In my case I wanted to display:none a few irrelevant div's.

I didn't want to store the HTML locally then load from the file, so I came up with another solution, conceptually similar to others here but more to my tastes.  This is Swift 3.  Have this run after the page loads, but before it's displayed:

```
let css = "#someDiv {display:none;} #otherDiv {display:none;} .someClass {display:none;}"
let js = "var sheet = document.createElement('style');sheet.innerHTML = \"\(css)\";document.body.appendChild(sheet);"
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: js)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this should do the trick? (Not tested in Xcode):

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{

  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
  NSString *cssPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.css"]; 

  NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var cssNode = document.createElement('link');"
                  "cssNode.type = 'text/css';"
                  "cssNode.rel = 'stylesheet';"
                  "cssNode.href = '%@';", cssPath];
  js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cssNode);", js];


  NSString *k = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var script = %@; %@", cssPath, js];

   //m_webview is a member 
   [m_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:k];
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it still looks the same. I wonder, how can I tell if 'stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString' worked or failed?

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5:

Before Show WebSite inject css to html

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        config()
    }

    private func config(){

        webView.navigationDelegate = self

        guard let url = URL(string: "url") else {
            return
        }

        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))

    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        let css = "Css Code"
        let js = "var style = document.createElement('style'); style.innerHTML = '\(css)'; document.head.appendChild(style);"
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(js, completionHandler: nil)
    }


}
```